# Azure Devops Connectivity\build agent issues post IIS Website URL change

Tags: azure, azure-devops, build-agent

We are using Azure Devops 2019 (App and data tiers are on different servers),We have done a domain migration due to which we had to change  Devops URL from https:\Devops.OldDomain.com to https:\Devops.NewDomain.com

Below are the steps followed

1. Changed URL on IIS Devops Site and applied a third party certificate for https ( made sure certificates are added to trusted Root Cert)
2. Changed Public URL (changed the url to new Devops Url) from Devops admin console ( verified the access point from tbl_AccessMapping and updated it to new url)
3. Restarted the Devops server

Below are the issues identified

1)I have noticed build agents stopped working\offline and when I try to setup new agents, I see below
"An error occurred while sending the request.Failed to connect. Try again or ctrl-c to quit"

tried changing agent file to correct url (yet no luck)

2)When I launch Azure devops admin console I see below error

[image]

3. When I try to add Devops url from visual studio (Visual studio is installed inside Devops server) I see below error
   "TF400324:Azure Devops services are not available from server, The underlying connection was closed"

Am I missing anything? I understand that some communication is missing between Application and Data tire, but I could not identify whats going wrong

Comment: It seems that your DevOps server can't connect to the database. Are you able to connect to target SQL Server database from DevOps server application tier machine? If the database is different, you may need to remap it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/backup/restore-data-different-instance?view=azure-devops#step-9-redirect-azure-devops-server-to-remote-collection-databases

Comment: Thanks for response, Everything seems working fine (like code commits, email alerts, creating new project collections  etc) except build agents. We have self hosted agents on app tier and those agents stopped working post migration

Comment: Are you able to setup a new agent on the same machine as your DevOps server? The errors should be save to the log file in _dialog folder.

Comment: I have tried creating new agent, below is the log message from recent trial

[2020-07-20 08:25:51Z ERR  Terminal] WRITE ERROR: An error occurred: Not configured
[2020-07-20 08:25:51Z ERR  AgentProcess] System.InvalidOperationException: Not configured
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Listener.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.LoadSettings()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Listener.Agent.ExecuteCommand(CommandSettings command)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Listener.Program.MainAsync(IHostContext context, String[] args)

Comment: It is too simple, are there detail errors?

Comment: I do not find any option here to share the complete log, can you provide me a MSDN link to upload complete logs?

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear the following caches:

- Clear TFS caches `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\x.0\Cache`
- Delete the contents of the Cache directory, including all subfolders.
- Regarding VS, close all Visual Studio instances, delete %LOCALAPPDATA%.IdentityService.
- Reset IIS by pressing Win+R, and input `iisreset` in the Run.

Comment: Thanks for response, I have tried all the above steps (yet no luck). 
Also when I click Admin console and click on Group member ship It gives below error TF400324 (The underlying connection was closed) 

From event log I see below <ExceptionType>Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.DatabaseNotFoundException</ExceptionType> 
  <Message>Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.DatabaseNotFoundException: TF400579: Could not find a database with DatabaseId: 3 at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.DatabaseManagementComponent.GetDatabase(Int32 databaseId) at

Comment: Did you follow the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/move-across-domains?view=azure-devops to do the domain migration?

Comment: Yes, I have followed same for migration

Comment: Can you connect to the sever without https set up?

Comment: No, we just enabled https

Comment: Do you mean you can not connect to the server even without https set up? If you create a new service account in new domain, and use it to config Azure DevOps Server, how's the result?

Comment: Have you tried creating a new service account in new domain and use it to config Azure DevOps Server? How's the result?

Comment: Is service account mandatory for server installation or system administration user (administrator) can also be used instead of service account for Devops installation?

Comment: You must use service accounts to install any of the following Azure DevOps on-premises servers: Azure DevOps Server, Team Foundation Build. Check documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/account-requirements?view=azure-devops